# Linq query to get count like select 'iphone',count(*)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

SQL statement :

```
select 'iphone',count(*) from tablename where id=5
```

Result:

```
Name      Num
'iphone'  50
```

How should i do with linq to get the same result(SQL statement)?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show the code and explain what the problem is. If not, please explain why not.

Comment: Why just don't get count like `sequence.Count(item => item.Id == 5)` and then assign name for that count, depending on usage context?

Comment: i am trying to do a statistics and make a union with detail records

Answer (score 3):

```
var Result = new { Name = "iPhone", Num = yourSequence.Count(x => x.Id == 5) };
```